# Error while sharing WIFI connection with Hyper V

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, hyper-v

I'm following the following article [Using Your Windows 8 Wireless Connection Inside Hyper-V](https://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/using-your-windows-8-wireless-connection-inside-hyper-v/) to share my wifi connection into my Hyper V machine, but during the 11th step when I'm trying to share the connexion I get this error :

[image]

In the beginning I made sure that my IP address is set to be automatic, but I kept having the same error, then I tried to make the IP address of my shared connexion static, but always without any result, what should I do ?

Note that the source of the connexion is my smartphone (I'm sharing my 3G connexion via WIFI).